# Nuxt-pwa doesn't cache routes. Is it optional?

Tags: caching, routes, progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js, workbox

How to reproduce problem:

Create pages:
index.vue (has nuxt-link to=/huindex)
huindex.vue

1. Build&Run
2. Open `http://localhost:3000`
3. Click link to `/huindex`
4. Stop server
5. Refresh page and POOF! Get network error instead cached huindex page

Okaaay.

6. Open `http://localhost:3000` again and get it from cache
7. Click link to `/huindex` and get huindex page from cache

Okaaay.

8. Run server again
9. Open `http://localhost:3000/huindex`
10. Stop server
11. Refresh page and get huindex page from cache